# fuerte packages trying to link with mysqlclient

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying out the ROS fuerte release, various packages I try to build (e.g. gazebo_plugins) fail due to cmake trying to link with mysqlclient?!

```
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libvision_reconfigure.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
```

AFAIK it shouldn't link with those libraries at all?! How can I find out where the mysql dependency / link flags are introduced?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31359/fuerte-packages-trying-to-link-with-mysqlclient/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rospack depends gazebo_plugins
```

returns list of package dependencies, then running

```
rospack libs-only-l
```

on the list via a shell script should show that in this case [pcl_ros](http://ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) exports `-lmysqlclient`

```
$ rospack libs-only-l pcl_ros
pcl_keypoints pcl_registration pcl_features pcl_segmentation pcl_surface pcl_tracking  pcl_filters pcl_sample_consensus pcl_search pcl_visualization pcl_io pcl_kdtree pcl_octree flann_cpp flann_cpp-gd pcl_common mysqlclient pcl_ros_tf rosbag nodeletlib uuid poco_lite boost_fs_wrapper tinyxml roslib bondcpp message_filters roscpp rostime rosconsole roscpp_serialization xmlrpcpp dynamic_reconfigure_config_init_mutex tf boost_thread-mt BulletDynamics BulletCollision LinearMath sensor_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1